# How to set default values in Google forms

Tags: google-forms

I am creating one google form which has a field of date and radio button of yes and no option.

What I am looking for is :

1. Default value to be set as today + 15 days for date field.
2. Default value to be set as no for radio option.

Has anybody tried to set default values in google forms?

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Form doesn't have the placeholder. But when Google Form and Javascript are used, you can achieve this. So are those threads useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/21102684/7108653 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/2128367/7108653

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I understood correctly I had the same issue a few weeks ago.

Google forms has a feature that allows you to store your default answers in a "prefilled" link. 
You can achieve this by going to the tree dots on the top-right corner (more), and click on **get pre-filled link**. After that you just have to choose the answers that you'd like to have as default and click on the button that's on the bottom of the page, it might be **get link** or **submit**, or something similar (I have it on spanish so I don't know the specific translation).
The only thing left is make sure you send the new link you got.

Hope this was what you were looking for!

Answer (score 9):

The feature is a bit hidden, but can be found in the top toolbar as "get pre-filled link":
[image: Get Pre-filled link]